# RSS feed using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rss, xmlreader

I'm new to Java and Spring boot and I am trying to read and Parse RSS feed from a site.

**What's the issue:**
I need to read all the data from the feed and it'll be the paginated call.

**What's my solution:** I think, I can achieve it if I read the data in a loop unless I reach the end and there's no more data. My code is as:

```
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        int pageNumber = 1;

        do {
            URL feedSource = new URL("https://altaonline.com/feed?paged=" + pageNumber);
            SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedSource));

            pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
        }
        while ( pageNumber <= 27);    //Need to fix this.
```

**I need help with:**
If there's no data on this URL, it gives me exception. I am not sure, how to check if the URL is valid, or if there's any data to process. How to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't know if the URL is valid **unless** you make the http request. So in this case, it would be ideal to surround the code with a `try-catch` and handle the exception accordingly. In case the URL isn't valid or returning no data, it can be handled by catching `IOException`. In case the feed returned cannot be parsed or generated, it can be handled by catching `FeedException`.

```
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    int pageNumber = 1;

    try{
        do {
            URL feedSource = new URL("https://altaonline.com/feed?paged=" + pageNumber);
            SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedSource));
            pageNumber++;
        }
        while (pageNumber <= 27);
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IO exception occurred due to: "+ ex);
        //Handle this exception accordingly
    } catch (FeedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Feed exception occurred due to: "+ ex);
        //Handle this exception accordingly
    }
```

You may even catch `Exception` at the bottom for handling any other unknown exceptions that may occur. Please note that `System.out.println` is only given as an example and ideally should be replaced by using a logging library.

Comment: @FayzaNawaz did this help you?